# XPath Match Nodes with Only <br> Tags

Tags: xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to target all nodes which contain only line break tags tags. I'm using the below expression:

```
//*[br and not(*[not(self::br)])]
```

This almost works but it also captures nodes which contain free text:

```
<p>
    This node should be omitted from results
    <br />
    More sample text
</p>
```

How would I only capture nodes structured like below:

```
<p>
    <br />
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. This should do it:

```
//*[br and not(node()[not(self::br)])]
```

Another alternative:

```
//*[br and count(br) = count(node())]
```

Comment: Thank you JLRishe! Both of those do the trick. I appreciate you providing multiple solutions. I think I'll go with the second solution as it's easier to read for an xpath rookie.